# Find emojis in messages and then react using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji, replit

I am trying to make a discord bot that finds emojis in messages in a channel and then reacts with these messages.

My code is:

```
if message.channel.id == 645647298423613453:
      custom_emojis = re.findall(r'<:\w*:\d*>', message.content)
      custom_emojis = [e.split('<')[1].replace('>', '') for e in custom_emojis]
      for item in custom_emojis:
         await message.add_reaction(item)
```

and it perfectly reacts with all custom emojis (I used resources from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615363/discord-py-custom-emoji-reaction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859876/how-check-on-message-if-message-has-emoji-for-discord-py)). So, now I have to implement the same for normal emojis.

The **first issue** is how to find if there are any of them in the message sent. In threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216665/find-there-is-an-emoji-in-a-string-in-python3) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text) it is used the module `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI`. However, as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544309/why-client-emojis-newer-version-of-client-get-all-emojis-returns-empy-list-wh) you cannot use it, right?

The **second issue** is that the only way that I have found how do react with them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362952/reacting-messages-with-emojis-in-discord-py).

I know that `await message.add_reaction("")` works perfectly but I lack the icon itself.

When I run this:

```
msg = message.content.split()
print("msg is ", msg)
```

I get this list: msg is  `['', '️\u200d⚧️', 'dasdass', 'aadsdasasd', '<:test2:1066037921007808612>']` while my original discord message was the knife icon, Trans flag, two random string and a custom emoji.

So the **final question** is: How do I get the  non-custom emojis, and how do I react with them in the format that I have extracted them.

For reference my code is hosted in replit.com and I have used this [source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/) to make the bot.

Comment: Get the list of non-custom emojis using the `emojis` library as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63909716/20214407). Then iterate the list (if not empty) and add a reaction per element (emoji) in the list: `[await message.add_reaction(r) for r in emojis.get(message.content)]`

Comment: @Jabro thank you for your advice. I did exactly what you have said but I get an error saying `AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'UNICODE_EMOJI'` obviously refering to the `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI['en']` command. This was my Issue 1 above.

Comment: Check the link I added above. I mean [this answer](https://i.imgur.com/rf6en0v.png)

Comment: ok thank you. So I added 
`import emojis`

`emoji_reactions = emojis.get(s)`

      `for item in emoji_reactions:

         await message.add_reaction(item)`
and it worked for all non custom emojis. So my solution and this compined work for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I implemented is this:

First I add the custom emojis:

```
custom_emojis = re.findall(r'<:\w*:\d*>', message.content)
      custom_emojis = [e.split('<')[1].replace('>', '') for e in custom_emojis]
      print(custom_emojis)
      print(message.content)
      for item in custom_emojis:
         await message.add_reaction(item)
```

And then I add the built in emojis:

```
s=message.content
      emoji_reactions = emojis.get(s)
      for item in emoji_reactions:
         await message.add_reaction(item)
```

This implementation has a small issue. You do not react with the emojis in the right order. Since there are two different sequential commands. But at the end there are all the reactions I want.